# JPA dynamically EntityGraph and Subgraphs

Tags: java, jpa

I created an util method:

```
public <T> Optional<T> fetch(Class<T> clazz, Object id, String... relations) {
    EntityGraph<T> graph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(clazz);
    Stream.of(relations).forEach(graph::addSubgraph);
    return Optional.ofNullable(entityManager.find(clazz, id, Collections.singletonMap("javax.persistence.loadgraph", graph)));
}
```

So if for example if `User` has lazy `orders` and `wallets`, I can do this:

```
Optional<User> user = fetch(User.class, 1, "orders", "wallets");
```

But I don't know how to take `orders`'s or `wallets` lazy collections. It would be greate if I would call method like this:

```
Optional<User> user = fetch(User.class, 1, "orders", "orders.products", "wallet");
```

How can I extend the method to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I decided to use the next method:

```
public <T> Optional<T> fetch(Class<T> clazz, Object id, String... relations) {
    EntityGraph<T> graph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(clazz);
    Stream.of(relations).forEach(path -> {
        String[] splitted = path.split("\\.");
        Subgraph<T> root = graph.addSubgraph(splitted[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < splitted.length; i++)
            root = root.addSubgraph(splitted[i]);
    });
    return Optional.ofNullable(entityManager.find(clazz, id, Collections.singletonMap("javax.persistence.loadgraph", graph)));
}
```

It has only one defect. The next two will work:

```
Optional<User> user = fetch(User.class, 1, "orders", "orders.products", "wallet");

Optional<User> user = fetch(User.class, 1, "orders.products", "wallet");
```

The next one will not:

```
Optional<User> user = fetch(User.class, 1, "orders.products", "orders", "wallet");
```

That's because `orders` overrides `orders.products`. I think it's enough, because logically if you want to load `orders.products`, you have to load `orders` anyway.